# How to make HTML open a hyperlink in another window or tab?

Tags: html, window, hyperlink

This is a line for a hyperlink in HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.starfall.com/">Starfall</a>
```

Thus, if I click on "Starfall" my browser - I am using FireFox - will take me to that new page and the contents of my window will change. I wonder, how can I do this in HTML so that the new page is opened in a new window instead of changing the previous one? Is there such a way in HTML?

And if yes, is there a way to open the requested page in another tab (not another window) of my browser?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

```
<a href="http://www.starfall.com/" target="_blank">Starfall</a>
```

Whether it opens in a tab or another window though is up to how a user has configured her browser.

Comment: Not all browsers support tabs and in those that do, pages opening in a new tab vs. a new window is a user-configurable setting.  There is no current way to specify a link needs to open in a tab vs. a window.

Comment: remember that the target attribute has to be declared AFTER the href attribute

Answer (score 109):

Simplest way is to add a target tag.

```
<a href="http://www.starfall.com/" target="Starfall">Starfall</a>
```

Use a different value for the target attribute for each link if you want them to open in different tabs, the same value for the target attribute if you want them to replace the other ones.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the target doesn't have to be '_blank'.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a valid HTML5.

Comment: What do you mean by 'name'?

Answer (score 9):

use `target="_blank"`

`<a target='_blank' href="http://www.starfall.com/">Starfall</a>`

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to add

```
target="_blank"
```

like

```
<a href="http://www.starfall.com/" target="_blank">Starfall</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

The `target` attribute is your best way of doing this.

```
<a href="http://www.starfall.com" target="_blank">
```

will open it in a new tab or window. As for which, it depends on the users settings.

```
<a href="http://www.starfall.com" target="_self">
```

is default. It makes the page open in the same tab (or iframe, if that's what you're dealing with).
The next two are only good if you're dealing with an iframe.

```
<a href="http://www.starfall.com" target="_parent">
```

will open the link in the iframe that the iframe that had the link was in.

```
<a href="http://www.starfall.com" target="_top">
```

will open the link in the tab, no matter how many iframes it has to go through.

Comment: how do i use that colored text in everyone elses examples?

Answer (score 6):

the target = _blank is will open in new tab or windows based on browser setting.

To force a new window use javascript onclick all three parts are needed. url, a name, and window width and height size or it will just open in a new tab.

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://www.starfall.com/','name','width=600,height=400')">Starfall</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also accomplish this by adding the following to your page's header:

```
<base target="_blank">
```

This will make ALL links on your page open in a new tab

Answer (score 5):

Since web is evolving quickly, some things changes with time. For security issues, you might want to use the `rel="noopener"` attribute in conjuncture with your `target="_blank"`.

Like stated in [Google Dev Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/noopener), the other page can access your window object with the `window.opener property`. Your external link should looks like this now:

```
<a href="http://www.starfall.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Starfall</a>
```

Comment: `<a href="http://www.starfall.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Starfall</a>` these days it seem to be best practice to have both

Answer (score 1):

below example with `target="_blank"` works for Safari and Mozilla

```
<a href="http://www.starfall.com" `target="_blank"`>
```

Using `target="new"`worked for Chrome

```
<a href="http://www.starfall.com" `target="new"`>
```

Comment: what distinguishes your answer among dozen of others?