# Weblink in documentation and maintain a "back" ("myLib/index.html") link header

Tags: doxygen

I have a library (let´s call it "*myLib*") documented using Doxygen that does some (external) references/linking; for that I am using the `<a href="../path/to/other/documentation/page/index.html">OtherDoc</a>` syntax. That´s perfectly fine; working properly. The side effect is that when I click on the link (and goes to the *OtherDoc* page) I have no way to go back to *myLib* if not using the browser "go back" button.

What I was thinking so solve this issue is to maintain a "myLib" header (or as a "footnote") when the user goes to the "OtherDoc" linked page. My question is: How do I do that in Doxygen?
Also, is there a better way to solve this "back link" issue?

Obs: The "OtherDoc" html pages are also doxygen generated documentation of another library I have, but it (OtherDoc) doesn't know about "myLib"; so, I would not like to put links on its documentation to "myLib".

Thanks in advance.
[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you lookup the use of TAG files within Doxygen.  These would allow you to reference "OtherDoc" classes (etc) from "myLib" in the normal "Doxygen" way.

This by itself will not allow "back-links" from "OtherDoc" - without modifying the HTML there.

An alterate approach would be to have Doxygen generate to a "wiki" format; which would allow "trails" and back links to be generated dynamically.  However, I am not aware of anyone doing this type of thing at the present time.

Comment: Just a quick update - the latest version of Doxygen (1.8.8 at time of writing) now supports a `BREAD_CRUMB_TRAIL` configuration option.  If set to `YES` then the complete bread crumb trail for a page will be displayed rather than just the root group.  I have not yet seen this in action though.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add back links in the `OtherDoc` documentation to `myLib` then why don't you simply have the link to `OtherDoc` open in a new tab or window? This way the `myLib` documentation remains open and the user can simply change back to that tab. From [How to make HTML open a hyperlink in another window or tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2343939/623518) you could use

```
<a href="../path/to/other/documentation/page/index.html" target="_blank">OtherDoc</a>
```

for your links. Note the addition of `target="_blank"`.