# How to make HTML open a hyperlink in another window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following:

```
<p class="bigfont">
    <img width="4%" src="images/Youtube.png" class="float-left"/ >
    <a href="\\OC2-RMGFS\Public\Safety\runhidefight-eng.wmv" target="_blank" title="Response to an Active Shooter Emergency"><h6> FBI Video: Run. Hide. Fight. Surviving an Active Shooter Event</h6></a>
</p>
```

Based on my understanding, the `target="_blank"` would display the video in a new window. However it is not. What happens is it open the Window media player to play the video. I would like the video to play on a windowless window. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make HTML open a hyperlink in another window or tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343927/how-to-make-html-open-a-hyperlink-in-another-window-or-tab)

Comment: The functionality of this link will be browser dependent. Not all browsers can display videos directly in a browser window. Additionally, the wmv (Windows Media Video) format is not supported by HTML5, which would explain why it's opening in WMP on Windows.

Comment: "However it is not" — While it is useful to tell us what expected behaviour you don't observe, a good problem statement would tell us what behaviour you actually observed

Comment: Your HTML has errors in it. The DOM that code is generating is weird. [Use a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Comment: *the `target="_blank"` would display the video in a new window* — What `target="_blank"`? Your [mcve] doesn't include that attribute (so presumably is neither verifiable nor complete).

Comment: in your code there is no target="_blank". so please stop downvoting the people that want try help fast

Comment: @TypedSource:  Yes you are correct but again, as my question states, I am aware. It did not work

Comment: "a windowless window" — a whowhatnow?

Comment: What is a windowless window?

Comment: I mean a new window. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

WMV is not a [format supported by the HTML5 video player](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) in browsers. You should try converting your video to a support format like h264 (mpeg) or webm.

On top of that, you may want to create an actual `player.html` page that you can load in the newly opened window so that you're able to configure settings like autoplay, which player controls are visible, etc. This could also give you the opportunity to allow video format fallbacks in case one of the encoded video formats is not supports, another will be chosen.

You could avoid having to create separate player pages for each video by passing a query string parameter in the URL that tells the player page which video to load.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a few issues here.

## Forcing browser to open a link in a new window

It's important to note, that messing with expected browser's behaviour is morally wrong. You should always let user decide how he wants to open a particular link.

However, if you *really* need to know, here's the answer. In the past, attribute `target="_blank"` used to open links (and forms) in a new window, but it doesn't anymore. Since browsers got more friendly, it'll just open the result **in a new tab**.

If you want to **force** browser to open a link in a new window, you need to use `window.open()` function. However, I beg you, do not throw it around too much. If you absolutely need to implement this function, at least make it a little bit less evil, like the following (so you're only adding a class `.new-window` without ugly `onclick`-s or anything like that:

```js
(function(){
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('a.new-window');
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Note that it'll not work inside SO snippets preview because of the sandbox!
      // Try on http://codepen.io/xerif/pen/JWggoJ
      window.open(this.getAttribute('href'), '', [
        'width=' + screen.availWidth,
        'height=' + screen.availHeight
      ]);
      // Also note that array will be converted to proper string automagically
      // I used array for readability
    });
  }
})();
```

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/43333255">Normal link</a> / 
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/43333255" target="_blank">Open in a new tab (probably)</a> /
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/43333255" class="new-window">Open in a new window</a>
```

▲ [try it on codepen.io](http://codepen.io/xerif/pen/JWggoJ) (snippets on SO are sandboxed)

It's worth noting, that `window.open` should not be blocked by popup blockers as long as window originated from user's action. However, if you try to open a window without user initiating that action — silently, by something like a timer or keyboard event — it will be blocked.

## Unsupported media type

As other people have hinted, **there's no such thing as Windows Media Player** in web environment. It just doesn't exist. Forget you know it. Do it.

Instead, you may want to use [`video` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video). As I understand, FBI prohibits you from putting training videos on YouTube, so you'll need to convert them to more appropriate format, like `webm` or `h.264`. Then:

```html
<video src="\\OC2-RMGFS\Public\Safety\runhidefight-eng.mp4" poster="./images/Youtube.png">
  We can't play this video in your browser. Can you <a href="\\OC2-RMGFS\Public\Safety\runhidefight-eng.mp4" download>download it</a>?
</video>
```

Answer (score -2):

`target="_blank"` is an unreliable way to open a new window. It may open a new tab. This is completely controlled by the browser.

One trick is that `window.open()` will always open a new window, not a tab, if you feed it a width parameter: `window.open('https://www.google.com','','width=100')`

If you leave width out it may open a tab as well.

Comment: `window.open()` is very likely to be blocked by popup blockers built into the browser. `target="_blank"` is more reliable because it allows the user to choose how the link gets opened and doesn't get blocked.

Comment: Agree it is likely to be blocked by a popup blocker, disagree _blank is reliable in the sense that it acts inconsistently across browsers. Given OP's requirements, _blank is not a correct implementation.