# I want to create a link on the home page of my website that will take users to the next page say about us then another page contact

Tags: html, css, web

I have 3 html file(home about contact)
On the home file I want to make a link that will enable user to go to other pages any help will be appreciated I’ve been searching I have no one to ask I need to get this project done I’ve already made the links but how do I make them open the pages thank you

Comment: show us your code!

Comment: You can use <a> tags and provide the adress of other page lets say conatct.html as href="conatct.html"

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make HTML open a hyperlink in another window or tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343927/how-to-make-html-open-a-hyperlink-in-another-window-or-tab)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML - you can write a link Tag, by using a link tag you can manage pages ( home, contact, about ), there is a simple code example for you -

```
   !DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- link  -->
    <a href="your home file path ">Home</a>
    <a href="your conatct file path ">contact</a>
    <a href="your about file path">About</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The name of the folder is Coin

Comment: The name of the folder is Coin I have this code <a>href=“/Coin/About.html”>About  </a> and it still it’s not directing me to the about page from the home page